# why javascript add 1 to setInterval id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#interviehover').hover(function(){
            IntervalId = setInterval(sec, 500)
            alert(IntervalId)
        });
        $('#interviehover').mouseout(function(){
            clearInterval(IntervalId)
            alert(IntervalId )
        });
```

after mouseout event fires i get IntervalId with added 1; for example on hover it alerts 12059, but on mouseout 12060?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question, because it's not quite clear what you're after.

Comment: i mean - the same IntervalId has different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using 'hover' instead of 'mouseover'.
Hover seems to be triggered on both mouseover and mouseout:

```
$('#interviehover').mouseover(function() {
    IntervalId = setInterval(sec, 500);
    alert("hover:"+IntervalId);
});
$('#interviehover').mouseout(function() {
    clearInterval(IntervalId);
    alert("mouseout:"+IntervalId);
});
```

The signature for hover takes 2 functions, one for mouseenter, one for mouseleave:

`.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )`

Answer (score 1):

In your example `setInterval` is probably called multiple times, so that the value of `IntervalId` is overwritten.

Don't use `alert` in combination with `hover`/`mouseout` especially when debugging. The appearing alert window will lead to unexpected triggerings of those events.

Don't use a global variable that can overwritten like that, or could execute `setInterval` multiple times and you'll only be able to clear the last one.

`hover()` takes two arguments, one for the `mouseover` event, one for the `mouseout` event. Either don't use `hover()` and set `mouseover` and `mouseout`, or don't use `mouseout` and use both arguments of `hover`.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the error because your hover function runs twice when you only pass one function.

You can change it over to take two arguments, then it will stop what you are seeing:

```
var IntervalId;
$('#interviehover').hover(function() {

    IntervalId = setInterval(sec, 500)
    $('#result').append('Starting with ID: '+ IntervalId +'<br/>');
}, function() {
    clearInterval(IntervalId)
    $('#result').append('Cleared ID: '+ IntervalId +'<br/>');
});

function sec() {
    $('#result').append('Running with ID: '+ IntervalId +'<br/>');
}
```

Take a look at the above [**working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jYjqK/)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see when you look at the jquery hover method:

```
hover: function( fnOver, fnOut ) {
    return this.mouseenter( fnOver ).mouseleave( fnOut || fnOver );
}
```

If there is only 1 function supplied, it uses it for both enter and leave.
When you enter, it sets a timer. Then when you leave, it again sets a new timer.
The second timer ID will probably be the first time + 1
Although it is specified as being 'unique', big chance it is just implemented as being incremental (since that is also unique)